# Why doesn't this JavaScript code return either "Yes" or "No"?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

JavaScript

I want this to print "Yes" if the two polynomial functions are equal and "No" if they are not.

```js
for (var i=0; i>24; i++) {
  if (4 * Math.pow(i,3) - 12 * Math.pow(i,2) + 8(i) + (4) === 
      8 * Math.pow(i,3) - 24 * Math.pow(i,2) + 16(i) + (5)) {
    console.log("Yes");
  } else {
    console.log("No");
  }    
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `i < 24` not `i > 24`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues I am seeing:

1. It should be `i<24` instead of `i>24`.
2. If you want to multiply `8 with i` then do `8*i` instead of `8(i)`, otherwise it will treat 8 as a function and will throw `Uncaught TypeError: 8 is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an ascending loop, you want to use the less than operator `<`.

You also used an incorrect operator for multiplication with `8(i)`. If you wanted to enclose in parentheses it should look like `(8 * i)`.

Your code should look like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    if (4 * Math.pow(i,3) - 12 * Math.pow(i,2) + (8 * i) + (4) === 8 * Math.pow(i,3) - 24 * Math.pow(i,2) + 16(i) + (5)) {
        console.log("Yes");
    }
    else {
        console.log("No");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
for(var i=0; i<24; i++) {
    if (4 * Math.pow(i,3) - 12 * Math.pow(i,2) + (8 * i) + (4) === 8 * Math.pow(i,3) - 24 * Math.pow(i,2) + 16(i) + (5)) {
        console.log("Yes");
    }
    else {
        console.log("No");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Nice! But please change the `8(i)` to `(8 * i)`.